# SQL Query to select data based on year and month

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

I'm writing an ecommerce app and im writing a script to track the sales of items according to year/month.

I used this query here to get the distinct year-month dates from the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date)) FROM product_purchases WHERE product_id = 1
```

Which would give me an output like so

```
2017-11
2017-12
```

What im trying to accomplish next is to select data that match that year and month, for example 2017-11.

I've tried this query which returned 0 rows

```
SELECT * FROM product_purchases WHERE DATE(date) = '2017-12'
```

What would be the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: do you need it for a particular month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find records of some month, update your where clause to :

`where CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date)) = '2017-12'`

Answer (score 4):

Replace your `where` statement with this

```
CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date)) = '2017-12'.
```

i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM product_purchases WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date)) = '2017-12'
```

You can do this ultimately.

```
Select * from (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date)) as NewDate,Product_Id,
Product_Name FROM product_purchases WHERE product_id = 1) where NewDate='2017-12'
```

Answer (score 3):

`DATE(date)` will generate the full date format, which is not equivalent to '2017-12'. Try this instead:

```
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(date),'-',MONTH(date))  = '2017-12'
```

Or this:

```
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2017 AND MONTH(date) = 12
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help you

```
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2017 AND MONTH(date) = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course your query returns 0 row. Problem comes with your condition.
It should be:

```
SELECT * FROM product_purchases WHERE YEAR(date) = '2017' AND MONTH(date) = '12'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want data just to filter by year and month, use `date_format` on date column to match with desired year and month.

**Example**:

```
where date_format( date_column, '%Y-%m' ) = '2017-12'
```

If you want to summarize data by year and month, use `group by` on the format.

**Example**:

```
group by date_format( date_column, '%Y-%m' )
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM oc_customer  WHERE MONTH(`date_added`) = 1 AND YEAR(`date_added`) = 2016